# Proving that an analytic function that maps on to {$z\in \mathbb{C}| |z-2|=1$} from some connected open set is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

This is the approach I took to solve this but I got stuck.

Suppose$f=u+iv\in $ {$z\in \mathbb{C}| |z-2|=1$} and that $f$ is analytic on an open connected set.

Then we have that $(u-2)^2+v^2=1$. Since $f$ is analytic it satisfies that Cauchy-Riemann equations.

By partial differentiating the above equation with respect to $x$ and $y$ I got 
$$(u-2)u_x=-vv_x$$
$$(u-2)u_y=-vv_y$$
By multiplying these 2 equations and using the CR equations I finally got that 
$$u_xu_y=0$$
This is where I am stuck. If I can prove that $v_x,u_x=0$ then from that I can get that $f'(z)=u_x+iv_x=0\implies f $ is constant. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: This is not true, on $\Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$, let $f(z)=3$ if $\Im(z)>0$ and $f(z)=1$ if $\Im(z)<0$. but if the open set is connected you result is true.

Comment: @Hamou Yes it should be connected I edited my question thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider invoking the [Open Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Comment: @user161825 I know but I am trying to prove this without using that.

Comment: How about mixed partials? Take the $y$ derivative of your first, and the $x$ derivative of your second.

Comment: @amcalde what are you referring to as first and second?

Comment: I meant your eqns that begin with: $(u-2)$

Comment: Wait, I don't think that will work afterall, just an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g = f - 2$. Then $g$ is analytic and has constant modulus $|g| = 1$. So $g$ is constant.

Here is a short proof. Write $g = u + iv$.  Then $u^2 + v^2$ is constant, implying that $uu_x + vv_x = 0$ and $uu_y + vv_y = 0$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations in turn imply that $uu_x - v u_y = 0$ and $uu_y + v u_x = 0$. Thus
$$u^2 u_x - uvu_y = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad uvu_y + v^2 u_x = 0.$$ Add these to get $(u^2 + v^2) u_x = 0$. Since $u^2 + v^2 = 1$ you get $u_x = 0$ in the open set.

You can show in a similar manner that $u_y = v_x = v_y = 0$ in the open set. As long as it is connected, $u$ and $v$ are constant.